# Is it practical to implement LINQ with an application that uses stored procedures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I am working on this `ASP.NET` project which is currently connected to a databases and uses `stored procedures` to add/edit/delete data. Do to the large of `stored procedures` in the database I would like to start using `LINQ` instead as the project is becoming difficult to manage (to find and test `stored procedures`)

So my question is, I know its possible, but is it reasonable to implement `LINQ` now? Is it practical performance wise to do so?

Comment: It's reasonable. I don't think you will gain anything from a performance perspective. However, I think there will be gains from an accessibility and maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Guthrie (a very respected authority) wrote an excellent article that talks about this exact topic.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

I don't think I would do it justice to summarize it here or transcribe portions of it.

To directly answer your question, I would have to say "it depends", which is a lame answer.  I could also say "yes, most likely" but it would be much better advice to suggest that you read what Scott Guthrie has to say about it and I think your answer will become pretty obvious to you.  After the first 4-5 paragraphs, you will get the concept and decide if it is something you want to do or not.

As a side note, if you are willing to consider technologies other-than LINQ, you might want to look at other ORMs (EF or NHibernate).  Each of them has their trade-offs and might be a more comfortable fit for the solution that you are describing.